# nivo slider on hover show prev and next buttons

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

Could anyone help me on this please. Is there a way to show Nivo Slider next. and prev. buttons only when the mouse is over the slides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some CSS for that. I don't know the exact elements without some sample code, but the essence is this :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div> <!--STUFF--></div>
    <div class="navigation-links"><!--LINKS--></div>
</div>
```

for the above simplistic markup, just use the following CSS:

```
.parent .navigation-links { display:none; }
.parent:hover .navigation-links { display:block; }
```

and you should have the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Here is the CSS code for the buttons.                                                             /* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
 position:absolute;
 top:90%;
 z-index:9;
 cursor:pointer;
}

Comment: you need to go one level higher. In your snippet, `.nivo-directionNav` is the equivalent of the `.navigation-links` in my example